# Better way of choosing foreign key option in django admin? (without the traditional dropdown and a method which allows filtering)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is there a better way of selecting foreign key of a model in django admin? At the moment, the selection is the traditional dropdown, however, it is not scalable.

Is there a feature which enables, perhaps a pop-up windows, which allows filtering the foreign key options (by its own foreign key) and choosing?

Comment: Have you tried the [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) or [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) options?

Comment: oh thanks for pointing that out. raw_id_fields solved the issue.